# Database Adapter for Geddy

Tags: node.js, database-connection, geddy

Is there a good documentation for Database Adapters for Geddy. I am trying to implement saving of the model data in geddy in an sqlite or similar database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're implementing this stuff now, keep track of the progress here: https://github.com/mde/geddy/pull/78

Comment: I see that the pull request is merged and that's great. It would have been even better if we had some documentation other than the comments on the pull request or the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @EgeÖzcan - we'll be updating the documentation soon.

Comment: @EgeOzcan there's info on the [Wiki Page for Model Adapters](https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Model-Adapters)

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented now and the documentation is on the [Wiki Page for Model Adapters](https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Model-Adapters)

Comment: There is also new documentation for the whole framework: http://geddyjs.org/documentation